# How can you determine whether a word with the pseudo- prefix should be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation, prefixes, morphology

I am in a bit of a quandary over conflicting results in dictionary entries about the inclusion of a hyphen in some of the words containing the pseudo- prefix.

An example of one of these words is pseudoscience/pseudo-science.

The [Oxford dictionary's entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pseudoscience) omits the hyphen for the word (i.e. they spell it as 'pseudoscience').

Meanwhile, [Cambridge's dictionary entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pseudo-science) decides to place a hyphen between the prefix and 'science' (i.e. they spell it as 'pseudo-science').

Another example would be pseudo-intellectual/pseudointellectual. [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pseudo-intellectual) includes the hyphen; [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pseudointellectual) does not.

I usually check more than one dictionary to see if a word with this prefix should be hyphenated or not. However, I am not sure which form to use in this case. Is there a way of determining which one?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general rule for hyphenation when creating compound words.

When in doubt, I look it up. If still unsure, I use a hyphen, as I won't be penalised for it. If still looks wrong with a hyphen, leave the hyphen out.

(native speaker, UK. See author Lynn Truss for style guidance on hyphens!)

Comment: It would be good to include some quote from Truss.